# Getting my sql database to work with my hit counter code in asp.net

Tags: c#, html, sql, database

I been trying to follow this tutorial to create a hit counter for my website using asp.net/c# and html/css. I'm running this off localhost. I'm having trouble configuring or getting the sql database connectionstring to work. Here is a link to the tutorial I'm using [Hit counter in asp.net](http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/database/hit-cntr-asp4-cs/). So I follow the tutorial and run the code, and i get this error

> Additional information: A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. The server was not found or was not accessible. Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. (provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 26 - Error Locating Server/Instance Specified)

I'm pretty sure it has to do with how i wrote the ConnectionString in the web Config file. Maybe I'm pointing the data source to the wrong place? Maybe it's because i'm not using Initial Catalog in the connection string?

connectionstring in my web config file:

```
<connectionStrings>
   <add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data 
    Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\Database.mdf;
      Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True"     
     providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
</connectionStrings>
```

calling my connectionstring from .cs file

```
 /objects we will need to work with the db
        SqlConnection conn;
        SqlCommand cmd;

        //IF PAGE IS NOT A POSTBACK, ADD A HIT
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            //connect to the db
            conn = new   
             SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings
             ["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

            //the sql command to increment hits by 1
            cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE Hits SET Hits = Hits+1 WHERE 
            Name=@Name", conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            //update where Name is 'About' which corresponds to this page
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", "About");

            using (conn)
            {
                //open the connection
                conn.Open();
                //send the query
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
```

I'm still a newbie when it comes to all this database stuff, any help be appreciated.

update fixed: I followed the instructions by user1551066 and found my data source for the database.mdf and then i plugged it in my connectionstring in web config and it WORKED.

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="ConnectionString" connectionString="Data Source= 
   (LocalDB)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\bobdole\Desktop
   \VideoWebsite\VideoWebsite\VideoWebsite\App_Data\Database.mdf;
   Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"/>
 </connectionStrings>
```

Comment: Your error states that the connection which you have established was not sucessfull.

Comment: Yea, dahsra, At this point I'm just guessing stuff. I just tried using initial catalog=database in the connectionstring, still same error. I don't know if it's a naming problem, or a pointing to a wrong source problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to connect to your .mdf database in visual studio. 1)Go to server explorer tab. 2)You should see your database .mdf file (possibly as DefaultConnection) 3) Click on it. In the Properties window you wil see the section Connection. Unfold it and you will see the ConnectionString property. Copy and paste it in your web.config ConnectionString setting.

Comment: If you weren't a man I would kiss you user1551066. Worked like a charm. The entire time I couldn't figure out what my proper data source was at. Once I fixed that and took out the user instance, it worked. THANK YOU.

Comment: Glad to help). But you need to keep in mind that it is not a universal approach and it works find only on your local server, however when you deploy your application on a production server the connection string must be changed in order to work correctly. So you will probably face the same issue with the connection string. Try to search your solution in the connection string reference mentioned below. It will safe your time in the future.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is due to SQL connection failure.Please check the connection string which you have passed was correct.For [connection string reference](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/) please refer here.

**Sql Server connection string**

connetionString="Data Source=ServerName;
Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
If you have a named instance of SQL Server, you'll need to add that as well.

```
"Server=localhost\sqlexpress"
```

and for connecting SQL Server

```
 string connetionString = null;
        SqlConnection cnn ;
        connetionString = "Data Source=ServerName;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;User ID=UserName;Password=Password"
        cnn = new SqlConnection(connetionString);
        try
        {
            cnn.Open();
            MessageBox.Show ("Connection Open ! ");
            cnn.Close();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Can not open connection ! ");
        }

  Please refer [here][2]
```